# Prevent vfio from loading for ethernet and wifi devices when using it for GPU

Tags: virtualization, proxmox, kernel-modules

```
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V SMBus Host Controller [8086:a3a3]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Comet Lake PCH-V SMBus Host Controller [1462:7c82]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] [10de:1b80] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] [19da:1451]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [19da:1451]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1462:7c82]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

I am using proxmox, passing through a GPU to a windows VM. All works fine but recently, vfio started loading as driver for the wifi card and the ethernet port I have on the motherboard. Leading to proxmox not being able to access the network anymore. I solved it by plugging a USB ethernet adapter and using that as main network device for Proxmox. Now I am trying to figure out a way to restrict vfio to only load for the GPU. As far as I understand, all three devices are on different IOMMU groups so I don't understand why this is happening.

Here is my GRUB config

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"
```

Comment: How could we tell why its doing that without seeing the configuration you used to make it do so?

Comment: all I have in /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf is options vfio-pci ids=10de:1b80,10de:10f0 disable_vga=1
 hence my question, why is this happening